# Beginner Node.js app using Heroku w/ Mailchimp API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, email, express.js

I'd like some feedback on the readability and style of the following code. It's a simple Node.js app that uses the Mailchimp API to add emails to a list. The client side handles SVGs, sign-up validation, and a contact modal with validation.

**index.js (Node entry point)**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('superagent');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});

var mailchimpInstance = process.env.MAILCHIMP_INSTANCE,
    listUniqueId = process.env.MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID,
    mailchimpApiKey = process.env.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY;

app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    request
        .post('https://' + mailchimpInstance + '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' + listUniqueId + '/members/')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + new Buffer('any:' + mailchimpApiKey).toString('base64'))
        .send({
            'email_address': req.body.email,
            'status': 'subscribed'
        })
        .end(function (err, response) {
            if (response.status < 300 || (response.status === 400 && response.body.title === 'Member Exists')) {
                res.send(true);
            } else {
                res.send(false);
            }
        });
});
```

**main.js (client side)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    emailjs.init("user_e00V3mHLZYEOvZAHpjKOt");

    $('img[src$=".svg"]').each(function () {
        var $img = jQuery(this);
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src');
        var attributes = $img.prop("attributes");

        $.get(imgURL, function (data) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

            // Remove any invalid XML tags
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

            // Loop through IMG attributes and apply on SVG
            $.each(attributes, function () {
                $svg.attr(this.name, this.value);
            });

            // Replace IMG with SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);
        }, 'xml');
    });
});

$('#signup-form').on('submit', function () {
    var data = {};
    var emailInput = document.getElementById('email');
    data.email = emailInput.value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        datatype: 'json',
        url: '/signup',
        success: function (returns) {
            if (returns) {
                showSuccess('#email')
                swal('Congratulations!', 'Please check your email to confirm your subscription.', 'success')
            } else {
                showError('#email')
                swal({
                    title: 'Error!',
                    text: 'Please check your email address again.',
                    type: 'error'
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});

$('.toggle-modal').on('click', function () {
    $('#contact-modal').toggleClass('is-active');
});

$('#contact-button').on('click', function () {
    var email = document.getElementById('email-input').value;
    var name = document.getElementById('name-input').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message-input').value;

    var valid = true
    valid = isValid(name, '#name-input');
    valid = isValid(email, '#email-input');
    valid = isValid(message, '#message-input');

    if (valid) {
        $('#contact-button').toggleClass('is-loading');
        emailjs.send(
            "gmail",
            "contact_me", {
                "reply_to": email,
                "from_name": name,
                "message_html": message
            }
        ).then(function (response) {
            resetForm();
            swal('Thanks!', 'You\'ll be hearing from us shortly.', 'success')
        }, function (err) {
            resetForm();
            swal({
                title: 'Error!',
                text: 'Please try again later.',
                type: 'error'
            });
        });
    }
});

function resetForm() {
    // Remove loading state and close the modal
    $('#contact-button').toggleClass('is-loading');
    $('#contact-modal').toggleClass('is-active');

    var ids = ['#name-input', '#email-input', '#message-input']
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        input = ids[i]
        $(input).val('');
        $(input).removeClass('is-success');
        $(input).removeClass('is-danger');
        $(input + '-success').addClass('is-hidden');
        $(input + '-warning').addClass('is-hidden');
    }
}

function isValid(value, input) {
    if (isEmpty(value) || isBlank(value)) {
        showError(input)
        return false
    } else {
        showSuccess(input)
        return true;
    }
}

function showError(input) {
    $(input).removeClass('is-success');
    $(input).addClass('is-danger');
    $(input + '-success').addClass('is-hidden');
    $(input + '-warning').removeClass('is-hidden');
    $(input + '-button').addClass('is-danger');
}

function showSuccess(input) {
    $(input).removeClass('is-danger');
    $(input).addClass('is-success');
    $(input + '-success').removeClass('is-hidden');
    $(input + '-warning').addClass('is-hidden');
    $(input + '-button').removeClass('is-danger');
    $(input + '-button').addClass('is-primary');
}

function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}

function isBlank(str) {
    return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
}
```

Full code available here - [https://github.com/leerob/Drink](https://github.com/leerob/Drink/tree/3fbc0123b0cadf3843f8bb061836ca47f8eb4840)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never worked with JQuery, but I can give you a few tips on the node part:

First, **define a project structure**. Separate the code in different files and directories for easier reading as well as making it more scalable:

```
src
|_ endpoints
|   |_ routes.js
|   |_ mailchimp.endpoint.js
|
|_ config
|   |_ db.config.js
|
|_ app.js
```

Secondly, here are a few overall tips:

- Prefer the use of `let`/`const` always over `var`. You won't be needing `var` again. Ever.
- Use ES6 [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and, in case they're a one-liner, avoid the brackets.
- Use the express [`router`](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)
- Use [`use strict`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) as a best practice.

---

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('superagent');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

require('./endpoints/routes.js')(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port')));

module.exports = app;
```

**routes.js**

```
'use strict';

const app = require('express');

const mailchimp = require('./mailchimp.endpoint.js');

const routes = (app) => {
    app.use('', mailchimp);
};

module.exports = routes;
```

**mailchimp.endpoint.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

const mailchimpInstance = process.env.MAILCHIMP_INSTANCE,
    listUniqueId = process.env.MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID,
    mailchimpApiKey = process.env.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY;

const requestMailchimp = (req, res) => {
    request
        .post('https://' + mailchimpInstance + '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' + listUniqueId + '/members/')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + new Buffer('any:' + mailchimpApiKey).toString('base64'))
        .send({
            'email_address': req.body.email,
            'status': 'subscribed'
        })
        .end((err, response) => {
            if (response.status < 300 || (response.status === 400 && response.body.title === 'Member Exists')) {
                res.send(true);
            } else {
                res.send(false);
            }
        });
};


router.post('/signup', requestMailchimp);
module.exports = router;
```